# Saxon HE select node in xml document

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, saxon, xpath-2.0

I am having trouble selecting one node or a list of nodes inside a xml document.
Without SAXON HE I would do this as:

```
xmlDocument.load(someDocument);
var node = xmlDocument.SelectNodes(path);
foreach(var nod in node) { //doSomething}
```

and then you could do:

```
nod.SelectSingleNode(path);
```

and you could have

```
/../SomeElement
```

in path, so you know you would go out of this element, to check for some different element in xml document...
But in saxon I only found a way:

```
                Processor xmlDetailProcessor = new Processor();
                DocumentBuilder detailBuilder = xmlDetailProcessor.NewDocumentBuilder();
                XdmNode xdmDetailNode = detailBuilder.Build(detail); 
                XPathCompiler detailCompiler = xmlDetailProcessor.NewXPathCompiler();
                detailCompiler.DeclareNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

Which selects node but is not aware of the whole element so you cant go up to some other element...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by using copy of xml document.. When I got to element which is repeteating through code, I put all same elements in list, and temporarily deleted them from document, leaving only one... Then I evaluated expression for whole document(because it only contained one element of this type), and then changed current element with second one, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem, saying it "selects node but is not aware of the whole element". The result of evaluating the XPath expression is in general an XdmValue, which allows any value in the XPath 2.0 type system. If you know that your expression will select a single node, then you can get that node as value.getList()(0), and casting the resulting XdmItem to XdmNode. From the XdmNode you can access properties such as NodeName, NodeKind, and StringValue, you can get to the parent node using the Parent property, or you can do further navigation within the tree by using the XdmNode as the context item for evaluating further XPath expressions.

The API isn't really optimized for doing C# navigation around the tree; it's much better in Saxon to do as much of your processing in XSLT or XQuery as you can, rather than in C#. But you can certainly navigate around the tree from the selected nodes if that's what you want to do.

Comment: well, my problem is, that when I select some XdmNode, and child of this node is another node which contains xpath expression... this xpath expression can contain an if statement which can have some value from some different location in xml document as condition, not value from this node... if we have <root><condition>lala</condition><item1><item2>someXpath</item2><item1> </root> and our XdmNode is item1, someXpath cannot contain if statement with condition such as if(//Condition[text()=lala])...

Comment: Sorry, you're going to have to explain that a lot more clearly. I can't see any difficulty in using the API to compile and execute XPath expressions that were read from the source document.

Comment: at some point in document I get to node which have more occurences in document, but each has different values inside... for each of this elements I have to make call to server to write data to database... so when i find which element is repeating, I make XdmNode a = builder.Build(repeatingElement)... inside this XdmNode I have an xpath expression which refers to element outside of this node, some where in document... because this node contains only its own children, I cannot evaluate expression if it refers to element outside of this element

Comment: Why are you building a new tree as a copy of the node, if what you want is the original?

Comment: because I have 4 same elements, and when it comes to an if statement it always comes to null because it only check the condition for the first element, not the other 3...

Comment: Sorry, I can't possibly help you debug your code from such cryptic clues. You're going to have to post your code, say what you're trying to achieve, and say how it's failing.